# What's the resource management contract for IEnumString::Next?

Tags: c++, winapi, com

I'm trying to implement an iterator over the [`IEnumString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-ienumstring) interface. I am having a hard time figuring out the precise contract of the [`IEnumString::Next()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nf-objidl-ienumstring-next) method.

The second parameter is documented as follows:

> `rgelt`
>
> An array of enumerated items.
>
> The enumerator is responsible for allocating any memory, and the caller is responsible for freeing it.

The part that confuses me is how to properly manage memory. Apparently, the `IEnumString` implementation allocates memory that the caller is requested to free. That seems to imply that the `OLESTR*`'s received point to memory whose ownership has been transferred to the caller.

Is this how the documentation is to be interpreted? If so, which allocator should be used to free the memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this Microsoft-authored sample on Github](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/SpellCheckerProvider/cpp/SampleSpellCheckProvider.cpp), the memory should be freed by calling `CoTaskMemFree`.

Start reading at line 91:

```
IFACEMETHODIMP CSampleSpellCheckProvider::InitializeWordlist(WORDLIST_TYPE wordlistType, _In_ IEnumString* words)
{
    unsigned int type = wordlistType;
    engine.ClearWordlist(type);

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    while (S_OK == hr)
    {
        LPOLESTR lpWord;
        hr = words->Next(1, &lpWord, nullptr);

        if (S_OK == hr)
        {
            hr = engine.AddWordToWordlist(type, lpWord);
            CoTaskMemFree(lpWord);
        }
    }

    return hr;
}
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable, though I'd rather have something more authoritative than sample code. Hosted on Microsoft's GitHub account or otherwise, the sample could be wrong, and `CoTaskMemFree` could silently ignore invalid pointers. There's no return value after all.

Comment: Raymond refers to it in https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130923-00/?p=3163 as well.

Comment: Everything implemented by Microsoft in COM uses  CoTaskMemAlloc/Free https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/memory-allocation-in-com with Visual Studio's ATL, you can use `CComHeapPtr<wchar_t>` which will handle all this automatically.